# Why does Stupefy not properly stun recipients during Dumbledore's Army training?

Tags: harry-potter, spells

During Dumbledore's Army training, members practice stunning and frequently hit each other. However we never see anyone being revived with Rennervate.

Is this because they are too young and not powerful/well trained enough at this point for the effects to be as severe?

In summary, **why do Dumbledore's Army members not feel the full effects of being stunned?**

Comment: I'm sure it says something like, "They revived one another and carried on," somewhere but I can't go searching right now.

Comment: @ThruGog It doesn't I don't think. What's interesting is it does talk about them standing around waiting for people who've had the Impediment Jinx put on them to come around by themselves (in *The Eye of the Snake*) but though they did practise stunning at the same time I can't find any aside about waiting for people to come round *or* using Rennervate or anything

Comment: Isn't DA in Order of the Phoenix, not Goblet of Fire?

Comment: Stupefy actually has varying degrees of effect throughout the books/movies

Comment: I'm curious what version of the books you have. My 2000 copy of Goblet of Fire has Diggory reviving his house elf with *en(n)ervate*, not *rennervate*.

Comment: This is one of those things that happens in the movies, not in the books. I can't recall any instance from the books where someone got hit by a stunning spell and didn't get stunned.

Answer (score 35):

After looking at the section in the book we know they were being stunned and falling down.

> ‘We’ll start with the Impediment Jinx, for ten minutes, then we can get out the **cushions and try Stunning again**.’
>
> they laid out cushions all over the floor and started practising Stunning again. - *Order of the Phoenix*

and from year 4 we know Harry and crew are already competent enough to revive each other.

> Harry was concentrating on the Stunning Spell, which he had never used before...‘Can’t we kidnap Mrs Norris?’ Ron suggested during
>   Monday lunchtime, as he lay flat on his back in the middle of
>   their Charms classroom, having just been **Stunned and re-
>   awoken** by Harry for the fifth time in a row. -*Goblet of Fire*

Comment: I *knew* it ;-)

Comment: Thanks. We might know they are being stunned and falling down, but do we know that they have to be revived? Looking at the second quote, maybe we just have to assume that because they are in Charms class they will be in DA training.

Comment: @user82081: I suspect it's one of those little details that just isn't important to the story as a whole -- if JKR noted every time even just Harry/Ron/Hermione cast a spell, it would have taken more than 7 books (or 8 movies).

Answer (score 3):

You have the answer right inside your question.

> because they are too young and not powerful/well trained enough at this point for the effects to be as severe

All of the wizards and witches are amateurs at that time, and stunning spells need a lot of practise and a certain level of expertise to pull off.